# Problems in creating wifi hotspot in ubuntu 16.04 for android device

Tags: wireless, 16.04, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

I've tried using the inbuilt connection manager to achieve this but when I `Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi network`, I get the following error:

```
(2) Connection 'Android-Hotspot' is not available on the device wlp2s0 at this time.
```

I've checked the network configuration file and the mode is set to `ap`.

I've also tried using `kde connection manager` but I still get the same error.

I've also tried `create_ap` but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Your adapter does not support AP (master) mode
```

I use a batch script to create hotspot on Windows 10 and it works perfectly but I am unable to create a hotspot in ubuntu.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the error "Your adapter does not support AP (master) mode" you should use another wi-fi card driver with AP mode support instead the default driver. How to do it ?

1. Detect the model of your wireless card:

lspci -nn

You should find a string like this:

09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY **[14e4:4315]** (rev 01)

2. Find the card manufacturer in this list:

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers

and select the item with "yes" in the "AP" column. For example,  I've selected "b43" driver for my BCM4312 LP-PHY card:

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/b43

3. Find your card in this list by Device ID ([14e4:4315] e.g.)
4. If you see "yes" in the "Supported?" column, you can use this driver for your wi-fi card. Otherwise, you should look for another driver. If the suitable driver is absent, you cannot create wifi hotspot in Linux. :-(

The driver install method depends of your card model. If you'll say me the model, I'll try to help you.